How do I call an application from another workspace?
I have different apps in a workspace, but want to call an application from another workspace.
I know how to call another app from within same workspace, but don't know how to call one from another workspace, and necessary things or steps to consider for configuration, safe navigation and other related process(es).
Please help or provide a link with more information. I am currently using Apex 23.1 with ORDS 21 and Tomcat 9.
Just to test, I created a blank page, added region + button, in button properties -> Behavior -> Action = redirect to URL and Target = /ords/myworkspace/f?p=101:1, when I run and press the button, it shows below error:


Workspaces are isolated. An app in workspace 1 does not know about any other workspaces on that instance. So to link to another app/page in another workspace you'll have to provide the full url

thank you @Koen Lostrie ,  i updated my opening post, please check.

How am I supposed to give any more information ? You don't say if (1) the app on the other workspace works, (2) what the url is of the app is on the other workspace (3) what url you are invoking. I'd say... your url is wrong but with the information I have i can't do anything else

thanks again @Koen Lostrie... now it works fine when i removed 'myworkspace/' from above mentioned Target = /ords/myworkspace/f?p=101:1 ... now the Target = /ords/f?p=101:1
